# Python Program, which asks user to input scores between 0 and 100 into the list

Tags: python-3.x

tried to solve this problem by myself, but there were mistakes in code. Hope somebody could help me.

```
def integer_list_input():
    print('Enter test scores between 0 and 100.')
    scores=[]
    while True:
         scores=input('Enter test scores: ')
         if scores>100 or scores<0:
            print('Invalid input. Score couldn\'t be negative or heigher')
         elif scores=='':
             break
    scores.remove(min(scores))
    return min(scores)
    q=sum(scores)/len(scores)
    return q
```

Here what the problem ask to do:

Write a program that keeps asking user to input a test score. The valid scores must be between 0 and 100 and there is no limitation on how many scores the user is allowed to enter. As it will be clear from the requirements listed below, it is not possible to process scores as they come and instead you will have to save the scores, as they are entered by the user, into a list. When user is done entering the test scores, they just hit enter at the program's prompt for next score and after that the program performs the following calculations:

1) find the smallest score in the list (you may want to take a look at function min() and read its documentation).

2) removes that smallest score from the list

3) calculates and prints the average of the remaining scores (i.e. sum them up and divide by the number of those remaining scores)

Comment: Can you describe how your code is failing to do what you expect?

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell us exactly what's wrong

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the input to an int first.

The input is actually a string, so you need to cast it into an int first.

And the add the number to the list.

You could change the code for this :

```
def integer_list_input():
    print('Enter test scores between 0 and 100.')
    scores=[]
    while True:
         score=input('Enter test scores: ')
         if score=='':
             break
         elif int(score)>100 or int(score)<0:
            print('Invalid input. Score couldn\'t be negative or heigher')
         else :
            scores.append(int(score))
    scores.remove(min(scores))
    q=sum(scores)/len(scores)
    print('Minimum is ':, min(scores))
    print('Average is ':, q)
    return [q, min(scores)]
```

Comment: You probably need to print the minimum before removing it from the list

Comment: Ty vary much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your code, I just cover the part concerning the input:

- You should use a different variable name for the list and the input.
- The `input()` function of Python 3 returns a string. You can't compare a string to numbers.
- You need to convert the entered string to a number before comparing it to the limit.
- You need to handle the case that the entered string is not a valid integer.

For reference, here is a function that reads a number, checks limits and returns `None` if the user just presses enter:

```
def readNumber(prompt, min, max):
    while True:
        raw = input(prompt)
        if raw == '':
            return None
        try:
            number = int(raw)
            if number < min or max < number:
                print('Please enter a number between ' + str(min) + ' and ' + str(max) + '.')
            else:
                return number
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter an integer.')

x = readNumber('Enter score: ', 0, 100)
```

Comment: Ty very much for your answer